# How does one flush rules on theme activation or deactivation only?

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

Flushing rules is clearly an important part of creating themes with custom post types. See [here](http://wpengineer.com/2044/custom-post-type-and-permalink/) and [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/wordpress-custom-post-types-breaks-permalink-on-theme-reinstall).

Does anyone have any example code of how to flush rules from functions.php?

I'm a little surprised this isn't covered in the custom post type pages of the Codex.

Update: I tried adding this to functions.php, but it didn't work:

```
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, array(&$this,'deactivate' ) );
function deactivate() {
 global $wp_rewrite;
 $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the solutions provided here do still work, WordPress has evolved since and does now (since 3.3, I believe) provide direct hooks for theme activation.

[`after_switch_theme`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/after_switch_theme) will fire on theme activation and [`switch_theme`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/after_switch_theme) before deactivating an old theme.

Hence the up-to-date answer is:

```
function reflush_rules() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'reflush_rules' );
```

Answer (score 2):

this code (taken from [Ozh's comment here](http://old.nabble.com/Activation-hook-exist-for-themes--td25211004.html) with small addition) may help you.

```
function reflush_rules() {
  if ( is_admin() && isset($_GET['activated'] ) && $pagenow == "themes.php" ) {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
  }
}
add_action('init', 'reflush_rules');
```

**edit:**

add this function on your `functions.php`. This function will only loaded when theme activated (the only time `$_GET['activated']` is set).

Comment: Nope, that didn't work.

Comment: Need to define $pagenow first. Added a new answer which does that.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about flushing on deactivation, but activation is pretty easy.

In your `functions.php` file, set up some code like the following:

```
function flush_rules_on_activation() {  
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $is_installed = get_option('theme_installed');
    if(!$is_installed) {
        $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
        add_option('theme_installed', true);
    }
}
add_action('init', 'flush_rules_on_activation');
```

This will run every time, but the rules will only be flushed once because you set a flag in your options table to prevent flushing them every time.

Comment: That code killed the whole page.

Comment: Just tested it on my own site ... it didn't kill anything.

Comment: Probably an error on my side. Although I prefer the Ozh solution.

Comment: I prefer Ozh's solution as well ... the only reason I posted this was in response to your "Nope, that didn't work" comment.

Answer (score 1):

I had to modify bangbambang's answer to get this to work.

The code should be:

```
add_action('init', 'reflush_rules');
function reflush_rules() {
$pagenow = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
if ( is_admin() && isset($_GET['activated'] ) && $pagenow == "/wp-admin/themes.php" ) {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What actually seem to work is adding this line after register_post_type:

```
flush_rewrite_rules( false );
```

Comment: This works, but it is inefficient, so you should not call it on every `init`.

Comment: OK, deleted in favour of an init hook. Don't really understand why, but taking your advice anyway.