# Serve apache 404 for missing assets rather then wp 404 template WP_Rewrites

Tags: htaccess, 404-error

I have a custom 404 page, but dont want serve it for every broken asset that may crop up. Instead I want to just serve the Apache 404 as its much faster. I've found the following htaccess rule that will achieve what Im after:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|swf|bmp|js|css)$ - [nocase,redirect=404,last]
```

But rather then manually placing it in the htaccess file before `# BEGIN WordPress` I'd like to programatically add the rule via the theme, as Im also trying to get my head around WP's rewrite API. My current rules are below with the crucial line added manually for testing:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^assets/css/(.*) /wp-content/themes/tr_roots_0.4.1/assets/css/$1 [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^assets/js/(.*) /wp-content/themes/tr_roots_0.4.1/assets/js/$1 [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^assets/img/(.*) /wp-content/themes/tr_roots_0.4.1/assets/img/$1 [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^plugins/(.*) /wp-content/plugins/$1 [QSA,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|swf|bmp|js|css)$ - [nocase,redirect=404,last] 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I've been looking a a lot of [examples](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5413/need-help-with-add-rewrite-rule) in and [effort](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/wordpress-url-rewrite/) to try to [achieve](http://www.prodeveloper.org/create-your-own-rewrite-rules-in-wordpress.html) this, but they seem inordinately complicated, and not directly applicable. Could someone take a stab at putting me in the right direction? This is what I have (not doing the trick) so far:

```
function tr_flush_rewrites() {
  global $wp_rewrite;
  $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}

function tr_add_rewrites() {
     global $wp_rewrite;
      $tr_new_non_wp_rules = array(
       '\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|swf|bmp)$' => 'nocase,redirect=404,last',
     );
     $wp_rewrite->non_wp_rules = $tr_new_non_wp_rules + $wp_rewrite->non_wp_rules;
}
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'tr_add_rewrites');
add_action('admin_init', 'tr_flush_rewrites');
```

Thanks for looking

Comment: why do you use the /assets/js/* etc rules instead of simply loading them from their location? Also flushing rewrite rules is a very expensive thing to do, your admin area is going to be very slow, you can flush rules by visiting the permalinks page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This very helpful page is unfortunately kind of burried on the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/User%3aAmereservant/Editing_and_Customizing_htaccess_Indirectly):

Basically mod_rewrite_rules hook will do the trick.

```
function faster_htaccess_rules( $rules ){
$faster_rules = <<<EOD
\n # BEGIN faster Apache 404 rules
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|swf|bmp)$ - [R=404,L]
#Use instead for network sites
#RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|swf|bmp)$ - [nocase,redirect=404,last]
# END faster Apache 404 rules\n\n
EOD;
return $faster_rules . $rules;
}
add_filter('mod_rewrite_rules', 'faster_htaccess_rules');
```

This prepend/apends the desired rules within the `# Begin WordPress` block, but outside of `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`. I had been exploring `add_rewrite_rule()` function, but it wont allow you to modify the RewriteRule flags.

Comment: I know this is from 13 but when you get a chance please mark this as the accepted answer.