# add_rewrite_rule with 3 or fewer matches?

Tags: permalinks, rewrite-rules

I've been reading around a lot on here and Google to do with custom rewrite rules in WordPress and `add_rewrite_rule`. I found [Jan Fabry's answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5413/need-help-with-add-rewrite-rule/5478#5478) particularly helpful, but I'm now a bit stuck.

I am using the following code to enable 3 matches in a URL:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpa5413_init' );
function wpa5413_init()
{

    // Remember to flush the rules once manually after you added this code!
    add_rewrite_rule(
        // The regex to match the incoming URL
        'our-work/our-year/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?',
        // The resulting internal URL: `index.php` because we still use WordPress
        // `pagename` because we use this WordPress page
        // `designer_slug` because we assign the first captured regex part to this variable
        'index.php?pagename=our-work/our-year&our_year_tax_slug=$matches[1]&our_quarter_tax_slug=$matches[2]&our_work_post_slug=$matches[3]',
        // This is a rather specific URL, so we add it to the top of the list
        // Otherwise, the "catch-all" rules at the bottom (for pages and attachments) will "win"
        'top' );
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpa5413_query_vars' );
function wpa5413_query_vars( $query_vars )
{
    $query_vars[] = 'our_year_tax_slug';
    $query_vars[] = 'our_quarter_tax_slug';
    $query_vars[] = 'our_work_post_slug';
    return $query_vars;
}
```

It is slightly modified from Jan Fabry's answer. I am using `([^/]*)` instead of `([^/]+)` although I have found that using either makes no difference to the result for me. I am also using it on a child page, so I've included the parent page in the initial regex match and the `pagename=` value.

It works perfectly well with all 3 values specified. When I use the following code in a template:

```
<?php 

    echo get_query_var( 'our_year_tax_slug' );
    echo "<br>";
    echo get_query_var( 'our_quarter_tax_slug' );
    echo "<br>";
    echo get_query_var( 'our_work_post_slug' );

?>
```

and access the URL like `test.dev/our-work/our-year/one/two/three/`. I get `/one/two/three/` printed on the page. The problem is, I also want these to work:

- `test.dev/our-work/our-year/one/two/`
- `test.dev/our-work/our-year/one/`

However if I try and access these URLs, I get a 404.

I tried adding two more sets of `add_rewrite_rule`s, like so:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpa5413_init' );
function wpa5413_init()
{
    // Remember to flush the rules once manually after you added this code!
    add_rewrite_rule(
        // The regex to match the incoming URL
        'our-work/our-year/([^/]*)/?',
        // The resulting internal URL: `index.php` because we still use WordPress
        // `pagename` because we use this WordPress page
        // `designer_slug` because we assign the first captured regex part to this variable
        'index.php?pagename=our-work/our-year&our_year_tax_slug=$matches[1]',
        // This is a rather specific URL, so we add it to the top of the list
        // Otherwise, the "catch-all" rules at the bottom (for pages and attachments) will "win"
        'top' );

    // Remember to flush the rules once manually after you added this code!
    add_rewrite_rule(
        // The regex to match the incoming URL
        'our-work/our-year/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?',
        // The resulting internal URL: `index.php` because we still use WordPress
        // `pagename` because we use this WordPress page
        // `designer_slug` because we assign the first captured regex part to this variable
        'index.php?pagename=our-work/our-year&our_year_tax_slug=$matches[1]&our_quarter_tax_slug=$matches[2]',
        // This is a rather specific URL, so we add it to the top of the list
        // Otherwise, the "catch-all" rules at the bottom (for pages and attachments) will "win"
        'top' );

    // Remember to flush the rules once manually after you added this code!
    add_rewrite_rule(
        // The regex to match the incoming URL
        'our-work/our-year/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?',
        // The resulting internal URL: `index.php` because we still use WordPress
        // `pagename` because we use this WordPress page
        // `designer_slug` because we assign the first captured regex part to this variable
        'index.php?pagename=our-work/our-year&our_year_tax_slug=$matches[1]&our_quarter_tax_slug=$matches[2]&our_work_post_slug=$matches[3]',
        // This is a rather specific URL, so we add it to the top of the list
        // Otherwise, the "catch-all" rules at the bottom (for pages and attachments) will "win"
        'top' );
}
```

But this did not work. I now only am able to access the first query var (`our_year_tax_slug`) even though `test.dev/our-work/our-year/one/two/three`, `test.dev/our-work/our-year/one/two/` and `test.dev/our-work/our-year/one/` all work without a 404 error, the template code only prints out the first value `one`, no matter which URL is accessed.

I'm sure someone must have come across this problem before, any help would be greatly appreciated. I am clicking saving permalinks every time I update the `functions.php file`. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well, apparently lots of trial and error pays off!

I used this code instead, where I reversed my `add_rewrite_rule`s and now it works perfectly.

```
// Remember to flush the rules once manually after you added this code!
add_rewrite_rule(
    // The regex to match the incoming URL
    'our-work/our-year/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?',
    // The resulting internal URL: `index.php` because we still use WordPress
    // `pagename` because we use this WordPress page
    // `designer_slug` because we assign the first captured regex part to this variable
    'index.php?pagename=our-work/our-year&our_year_tax_slug=$matches[1]&our_quarter_tax_slug=$matches[2]&our_work_post_slug=$matches[3]',
    // This is a rather specific URL, so we add it to the top of the list
    // Otherwise, the "catch-all" rules at the bottom (for pages and attachments) will "win"
    'top' );

// Remember to flush the rules once manually after you added this code!
add_rewrite_rule(
    // The regex to match the incoming URL
    'our-work/our-year/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?',
    // The resulting internal URL: `index.php` because we still use WordPress
    // `pagename` because we use this WordPress page
    // `designer_slug` because we assign the first captured regex part to this variable
    'index.php?pagename=our-work/our-year&our_year_tax_slug=$matches[1]&our_quarter_tax_slug=$matches[2]',
    // This is a rather specific URL, so we add it to the top of the list
    // Otherwise, the "catch-all" rules at the bottom (for pages and attachments) will "win"
    'top' );

 // Remember to flush the rules once manually after you added this code!
add_rewrite_rule(
    // The regex to match the incoming URL
    'our-work/our-year/([^/]*)/?',
    // The resulting internal URL: `index.php` because we still use WordPress
    // `pagename` because we use this WordPress page
    // `designer_slug` because we assign the first captured regex part to this variable
    'index.php?pagename=our-work/our-year&our_year_tax_slug=$matches[1]',
    // This is a rather specific URL, so we add it to the top of the list
    // Otherwise, the "catch-all" rules at the bottom (for pages and attachments) will "win"
    'top' );
```

I would guess this has something to do with the `'top'` parameter on the add_rewrite_rule. Most likely its some kind of other mystical magic I have no idea about. I'd be interested to find out exactly what is going on here though.