# How to write correct add_rewrite_rule in WordPress for more than one taxonomy in one rule?

Tags: permalinks

I have a database of locations and services, made using WordPress , each town / region / county is a custom taxonomy,
I wrote some custom rules to make slug clean but they (site owners) ask to remove town/region/county words! I tried but I can't achieve it, can anybody help me?

these are my URL examples

**/services/home-care/region/norfolk

/services/home-care/town/norbury**

and these are my rules

```
 add_rewrite_rule('^services/(.*)/town/(.*)?', 'index.php?post_type="ag_location"&ag_primary_inspection_cat=$matches[1]&ag_cities=$matches[2]', 'top');
    add_rewrite_rule('^services/(.*)/region/(.*)?', 'index.php?post_type="ag_location"&ag_primary_inspection_cat=$matches[1]&ag_regions=$matches[2]', 'top');
    add_rewrite_rule('^services/(.*)/county/(.*)?', 'index.php?post_type="ag_location"&ag_primary_inspection_cat=$matches[1]&ag_county=$matches[2]', 'top');
```

I want to have

**/services/home-care/norbury

/services/home-care/norfolk**

but don't think it's possible!
I have Vue.js codes in those archive pages that fetch data based on town or region or county type.

I guess can map all of them into 1 page, and in that page check type of term.
like

```
 add_rewrite_rule('^services/(.*)/(.*)?', 'index.php?post_type="ag_location"&ag_primary_inspection_cat=$matches[1]&ag_county=$matches[2]', 'top');
```

and in page taxonomy-ag_county.php

```
$term = get_queried_object(); // Get the term 
$slug=$term->taxonomy; 
$placeType="";

switch ($slug){ 
    case 'ag_county': $placeType="county"; break; 
    case 'ag_cities': $placeType="city"; break; 
}
```

I have a search form that loads those taxonomies like this:

[image]

Comment: How does backend know if `norbury`/`norfolk` is a `region` or `town`?

Comment: @kero Those are seperated taxonomies, I've updated the question content, maybe usefull

Comment: I understand, but how should your code understand? What happens if both taxonomies have the same term name? (So `/services/home-care/foo` where `foo` exists in `region` and `town`.)

Comment: @kero Exactly! so It's kinda impossible, right? P.S. Edited question again

Comment: I mean it can be done, you have to decide what happens. `region` could always take priority. But the whole thing is prune to errors and problems. So personally I'd try to convince the client to keep the slug, as this simplifies many things.

Comment: @kero Thank you for your comments

Answer (score 0):

Changed URL formats to be like:

**/services/home-care/COUNTY/TOWN**

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    'services/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?',
    'index.php?post_type="ag_location"&ag_primary_inspection_cat=$matches[1]&ag_cities=$matches[3]',
    'top' );


add_rewrite_rule(
    'services/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?',
    'index.php?post_type="ag_location"&ag_primary_inspection_cat=$matches[1]&ag_county=$matches[2]',
    'top' );


add_rewrite_rule(
    'services/([^/]*)/?',
    'index.php?post_type="ag_location"&ag_primary_inspection_cat=$matches[1]',
    'top' );
```

Based on [this solution](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/170096/8124)