# how to use mutliple add_rewrite_rule?

Tags: rewrite-rules

This is a follow up from the question

[How to attach region identifier to a pretty url?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/252723/how-to-attach-region-identifier-to-a-pretty-url/252843#252843)

I want to apply this `add_rewrite_url` to multiple pages?

I tried adding a 2nd `add_rewrite_rule` as follows:

```
add_action('init', 'country_selection_url');
function country_selection_url() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^teacher/([^/]*)/','index.php?pagename=teacher&country=$matches[1]','top');
    add_rewrite_rule('^parent/([^/]*)/','index.php?pagename=parent&country=$matches[1]','top');

}

add_filter('query_vars','country_selection');
function country_selection($query_vars){
    $query_vars[]='country';
    return $query_vars;
}
```

Is it becasue I removed the `?` at the end of the first parameter in the add_rewrite_rule? (IE: `'^teacher/([^/]*)/'` vs `'^teacher/([^/]*)/?'`

IF so why is the `?` so darn important?

Secondly using regular expressions is there a way that this add_rewrite_rule could be applied to all pages?

```
add_rewrite_rule('([^/]*)/([^/a-z]{0..2}*)/?','index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&country=$matches[2]','top');
```

The second part will be at most 2 characters long, but might not also be included.

Comment: Have you read `add_rewrite_rule` docs?

Comment: I did the wordpress ones are pretty lacking.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule

Comment: Ok, seeing that you read it: Do you know what the first parameter is?

Comment: Yes that is the url, I want the world to see, it's the pretty url i want to use. I'm not a wordpress expert, but I have been doing php dev for quite sometime. I just am picking up on wordpress.

Comment: First parameter is not a URL. You didn't read that in the docs. It says: _(string) (required) A regular expression to match against a requested URL._

Comment: So, if its a _regular expression_, maybe you should read about those, and you'd find out why the _darn ? is important_ (or not)

Comment: Thanks I will do that. So you know I honestly believed it was parameters separator from the url. I was wondering why it was required. :)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `rewrite_rules` option in the wordpress database's option table. I bet your answer is [end point](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint).

Comment: I read that document, and I found it very vague, and not really helpful.

Comment: End point is wordpress's power tool. Get your own way then.

Comment: See that's not helpful either...

Comment: I don't mind if anyone don't understand the use.