# How can i redirect one url to another url using .htaccess or add_rewrite_rule

Tags: htaccess, rewrite-rules, apache, mod-rewrite

I am stuck at redirecting one url to another url.

I want to redirect

```
https://samedomain.com/page-check-927GSJAYS639AL/highlights
```

to

```
https://samedomain.com/page-highlights/
```

(927GSJAYS639AL this is id it can be anything)

the `http://samedomain.com/page-highlights/` is the wordpress page

The rewrite rule I tied in .htaccess file (added this in the first line it-self) is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page-check-([A-Z0-9_-]+)/highlights$ page-highlights?id=$1 [L]
```

but I see a 404 error page

It worked for

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page-check-([A-Z0-9_-]+)/highlights$ info.php?id=$1 [L]
```

I also tried WP rewrite API php code

**UPDATE 1**

```
add_action('init', 'ao_add_rewrite_rule');
function ao_add_rewrite_rule() {
   add_rewrite_rule('^page-check-([A-Z0-9_-]+)/highlights/?$', 'index.php?pagename=page-highlights&id=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
add_action('init', 'ao_add_rewrite_rule');
function ao_add_rewrite_rule() {
   add_rewrite_rule('^page-check-([A-Z0-9_-]+)/highlights/?$', 'index.php?pagename=page-highlights&id=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpa5413_query_vars' );
function wpa5413_query_vars( $query_vars ) {
   $query_vars[] = 'id';
   return $query_vars;
}
```

Adding this line `RewriteRule ^page-check-([A-Z0-9_-]+)/highlights$ index.php?pagename=page-highlights&id=$1 [L]`  in .htaccess file works, but it will do 301 redirect, so the URL also changes back to `https://samedomain.com/page-highlights/`

No Luck :( in finding solutions

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possibly a silly question, but are you sure `page-highlights` is the actual slug of a page, and not just the _name_ of a template?

Comment: rewrites are not what you want, redirects are what you want, there are functions such as `wp_redirect` and `wp_safe_redirect` for that. HTAccess could do it but not using rewrites, and the WP rewrite rules are for mapping not for redirecting

Comment: @vancoder yes, you are right. i have been using  slug of a page. I am a new bee to this Wordpress. Could you please guide me how can I achieve this?

Comment: @TomJNowell if i use `wp_redirect ` the URL also changes , i am not looking for redirect rule here.
i just want to show `https://samedomain.com/page-highlights/` contents on `https://samedomain.com/page-check-927GSJAYS639AL/highlights`

Comment: @chandanaGowda that would lead to duplicate content, with both the new and old URLs serving the same data, and SEO penalties as a result. WP Rewrite rules always take the form of "pretty URL" -> "index.php?foo=bar" they can't be used to make "synonyms" or edit other rewrite rules, only add new pretty URLs that map to ugly permalinks. WP will always try to redirect to the canonical URL to avoid SEO hits. What is it that you're trying to redirect? Is it a page listed in the pages admin area? A custom post type? Where does the number/letters you're trying to remove come from?

Comment: @TomJNowell: thanks for the info! Previously I was using `http://samedomain.com/page-highlights/?id=GSJAYS639AL` url. For SEO purpose i want to show `http://samedomain.com/page-highlights/?id=GSJAYS639AL`  contents in `https://samedomain.com/page-check-927GSJAYS639AL/highlights` URL
`http://samedomain.com/page-highlights/` is the WP page.
yes, it is listed admin area. The custom type is page. the number/letters => ID is generated randomly for each unique page (will be stored in DB)

Answer (score 1):

I'm honestly struggling to comprehend this failure state - I believe I've reproduced the issue locally, and in my testing the `RewriteRule` directive hits but then WordPress processes the original input, resulting in a fairly catch-all attachment rewrite producing a query for a non-existent attachment. I may continue playing with it to try and figure out what's going on.

In the meantime, I think the root of the issue is complexity introduced by using a URI as the target of the RewriteRule. Using a file path seems to alleviate the problem:

```
RewriteRule ^page-check-([A-Z0-9_-]+)/highlights/?$ index.php?pagename=page-highlights&id=$1 [L]
```

Regarding the use of `add_rewrite_rule()`, I have a few notes:

- When you use a target which does not start with `index.php`, WordPress will write the rule to the `.htaccess` file and implicitly begin the pattern with the `^` character - thus, starting a pattern with `^` while using a URI target can result in malformed rule beginning with `^^`.
- Instead of positional references to matches such as `$1`, WordPress uses the syntax `$matches[1]`.
- Flushing rewrite rules is a fairly expensive operation - I'd strongly recommend against flushing them in routine hook!

The above in mind, an `add_rewrite_rule()` with using a filepath target akin to the above RewriteRule directive would look as such:

```php
add_action('init', 'ao_add_rewrite_rule');

function ao_add_rewrite_rule() {
   add_rewrite_rule('^page-check-([A-Z0-9_-]+)/highlights/?$', 'index.php?pagename=page-highlights&id=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
```

Comment: it solved my problem. Thank you

Comment: "the RewriteRule directive hits but then WordPress processes the original input" - The issue is internally rewriting the request to another "pretty" URL, which is then rewritten again to `index.php` (the WP front-controller). This will likely fail on any CMS/framework that uses a front-controller pattern, like WP. The intermediary rewrite is internal to Apache, occurring before WP gets to handle the request. WP looks at `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to retrieve the originally requested URL. (In this instance, you could look at `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']` instead but at other times this would fail.)

Comment: @bosco: I thought it was working, but it is redirected to https://samedomain.com/page-highlights/ in the inspect i can see `301 Moved Permanently`
this also failed :(

Comment: @bosco: i also tried this solution [Need help with add_rewrite_rule](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5413/need-help-with-add-rewrite-rule), didn't work for me

Comment: Pardon the late reply - are you still experiencing the issue?