# Custom post type permalinks

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

I have a custom post type called "number" and I would like to achieve URL's for it's "posts" to be the following http://website.com/post-name instead of http://website.com/number/post-name.

I tried to set the 'rewrite' parameter in register_post_type to: `'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => '', 'with_front' => false )`, but it didn't worked. Even if I saved my permalinks settings to flush it. (I have my permalinks set to Day and name - /%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/)

Do you have any ideas how to achieve it? I am doing a transfer of one website to WP and I would like to keep the current URL structure, so it will be safe for Google as well.

Thank you in advance for any tips.

Comment: Its advised not to have something before the post name mainly because it messes with how WP handles pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a rewrite rule in your .htaccess file to remove number from the link.

You'll need something along the lines of:

```
RewriteRule ^number/(.+)$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a plugin that will help you.

http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/custom-post-permalinks/tags/1.1.4

Install it, go to Settings > Permalinks and modify the field corresponding to the CPT.

Answer (score 0):

do you have update the permalinks after your activation of your code? Alternate you can refresh the permalinks via source in your functions with the WP function [flush_rewrite_rules()](http://wpengineer.com/2044/custom-post-type-and-permalink/).

You can also read this [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/wordpress-custom-post-types-breaks-permalink-on-theme-reinstall) and answer from here.

Comment: That will not help the above issue. Custom post type permalinks are set up to display as *post-type*/*post-name* even with_front set to false.